# Can we use group by and where condition with same fieldname

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement like have to pull all records in the date range the user selected, selecting all employees who started from 15-Jan-2011 to 20-Aug-2011 and group by date.

How should I write SQL query for this:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM employees 
   WHERE startdate >= '15-jan-2011' 
     AND startdate <= '20-aug-2011'
GROUP BY startdate
```

Comment: Your requirement doesn't make sense as written. If you have two employees that started on January 15th, what exactly do you want returned? Can you show some sample data and desired results please, including cases where multiple employees were hired on the same day? Also, if two employees have different salaries or names, what do you want returned? Maybe you misunderstand what `GROUP BY` does?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Absolutely. It will result in filtering the records on your date range and then grouping it by each day where there is data.

It should be noted that you will only be able to select the startdate and then whatever aggregates you're calculating. Otherwise, it should work perfectly fine.

For example, this query will give you a count of employees for each startdate:

```
SELECT startdate, count(*)
FROM employees 
WHERE startdate >= '15-jan-2011' 
      AND startdate <= '20-aug-2011'
GROUP BY startdate
```

Answer (score 3):

You can, but the "GROUP BY" clause is used for grouping together sets of rows, so it does not make sense for your question (or anything that involves a "SELECT *").

To answer your question though:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,StartDate)) AS 'StartDate', <other fields>
FROM   Employees
WHERE  StartDate BETWEEN '15-Jan-2011' AND '20-Jan-2011'
ORDER BY StartDate
```

Note: the stripping of the time from the date came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978839/to-get-date-from-datetime-in-sql/1978853#1978853)