# Returning the date only from a complete date

Tags: sql, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [To get date from datetime in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978839/to-get-date-from-datetime-in-sql)

in my table i have the column `date`

this is my sql code:

```
SELECT        [date], enterHour, exitHour
FROM            enterAndExit
WHERE        DATEPART(MONTH, date) = 10;
```

i want only the rows with the date 10.

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: That should return all rows in October (month 10.)  Perhaps you could clarify with some example rows which results you are getting, and which results you would like?

Comment: What RDBMS (and which version) ?? SQL is just the structured query language - not an actual database product ...

Comment: `date` is normally a reserved word; try `[date]`.

Comment: I think he's trying to get the date only without the time.  For example, if the date is 2012-12-25 13:05:49  he wants only 2012-12-25  I'm not sure how else "date only from a complete date" could be interpreted.

Comment: Bob is correct.. change `date` inside Datepart() function to `[Date]`

Comment: Never mind, The title and the code question don't match, my bad.  Should've read the full question better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this SQL instead:

```
SELECT   [date], enterHour, exitHour
FROM     enterAndExit
WHERE    Month([Date]) = 10;
```